# SQL Server database not publicly accessible through port 1433

Tags: sql-server, ports

Alright, I know this sounds pretty basic, but it is eluding me. I have a local server with SQL server 2017 installed (Express Edition, because - Free). I can access the database when remoted into the server without issue. The problem is when I try to access the server using the public IP rather than the local hostname. My router has this server in the DMZ currently and port forwarding is setup for port 1433. The server firewall is currently even turned off and I still cannot see it.

[image: Port Query Screenshot]

The SQL server does have TCP/IP enabled, it is listening on port 1433.

[image: SQL Server Config Manager Screenshot]

If you need any further information, let me know. I've been troubleshooting this for two hours and just lost at this point. I am no where near new to technology and servers, but not too familiar with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled remote connections.

http://web.synametrics.com/sqlexpressremote.htm

Comment: Remote connections are enabled.